# MISRA Violation 12.9 Operand of unary minus is unsigned

Tags: c, integer, implicit-conversion, misra

I'm currently dealing with some MISRA issues and therefore trying to understand the integer conversion rules in C.

I'm getting a violation of MISRA-C 2004 rule 12.9
*The unary minus operator shall not be applied to an expression whose underlying type is unsigned*

in the code line

```
signed long int test = -1;
```

I understand that there is no negative integer constant "-1", but rather the unary minus applied to the integer constant "1" (as stated in https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant).

The integer constant "1" however is of the first type in the list *int*, *long int*, *unsigned long int (until C99)*, *long long int (since C99)*

I'm compling with Keil (ARM 32 bits) and the --c99 flag set, while MISRA-C 2004 seems to be based on the C90 standard.

So it seems as my SCA tool is assuming the "1" constant is of type *unsigned long int (until C99)*, but I can't see, why it wouldn't fit in an ordinary *int* and therefore be signed.

To satisfy the SCA tool, one has to code

```
signed long int test = -1L;
```

or

```
signed long int test = -((signed long int) 1);
```

Is this correct behaviour or am I missing something here?

Comment: Curious, still get 12.9 violation with `signed long int test = 0 - 1;`?

Comment: Yet another bug in whatever tool is doing the analyzing. MISRAble

Comment: Well, it is always a good idea to add suffices to make things clear. ;-)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica No, that calculation is compliant, but imo too puzzling to actually use ;)

Comment: Actually I just remembered that there is a rule against implicit conversions to different types if the expression in a so-called "complex expression" (MISRA-C term), which is defined as everything that isn't either a constant expression, a lvalue or a function return value. In this case `-1` is a constant expression (as is `0 - 1`), so that rule does not apply.

Comment: @thebusybee Interestingly, the line `signed short int test = -1;` is not compliant, either, and since there is no short-suffix, it really seems to be a tool bug :/

Comment: Oops. Nice find! Tools are only humans\b\b\b\b\b\bwritten by humans. :-D

Comment: @RobertAlpha Please don't mix up the term compliant with "strange warning from my potentially broken static analyser" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The integer constant "1" however is of the first type in the list int, long int, unsigned long int...

Correct. Integer constants like `1` are of type `int` and as far as MISRA-C is concerned, the underlying type is also `int`. The definition is (MISRA-C:2004 6.10.4)

> The term "underlying type" is defined as describing the type that would be obtained from evaluating an expression if it were not for the effects of integral promotion.

The line `signed long int test = -1;` is MISRA-C:2004 (and MISRA-C:2012) compliant.

- The expression `-1` contains no implicit promotions in itself. Integral promotion does not apply.
- Thus `-1` has underlying type signed `int` and upon assignment, it is implicitly converted to a wider integer type with the same signedness, which is fine.
- The intention is to create a signed variable, so the rule about `u` suffix does not apply.
- Furthermore, the rule 10.1 against implicit conversions from a so-called "complex expression" into different a type does not apply either, since `-1` is a constant expression, not a complex expression (see MISRA-C:2004 6.10.5).

So this is yet another tool bug. The tool seems to picking the wrong underlying type of an expression, which would be a severe bug.

`signed long int test = -1L;` is not necessary for compliance, although it is also compliant code.